# linearity assumption Regression

Tags: least-squares

I fail to understand the need for the linearity assumption in the Gauss-Markov theorem and, even worse, I do not understand its meaning. We say that the model should be linear in the coefficients or parameters, implying that regressing $y$ on $x$ and $x^2$ is linear as the marginal effect would be $\beta_1+2\beta_2 x$, which is certainly a linear function of $x$.

However, if we would include a power $3$, the marginal effect would be $\beta_1+2 x\beta_2+3 \beta_3 x^2$, which is no longer linear. Thus this mean that it is wrong to include powers higher than 2 in a simple regression model?

Comment: The marginal effects are not linear when the model is quadratic.  You have confused this with the effect used in econometrics which is the first derivative, which is linear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linearity in parameters is different than in the covariates. Covariates can be transformed to be linear.

I start by an example. Assume the model is $y=\beta^2 x+e$ that clearly not linear with respect to the parameter $\beta$. We assume all typical assumptions of the linear model hold. To use the classical methods I assume $\phi=\beta^2$ . then the estimation of $\phi$ is given by

$$
\hat\phi=(x'x)^{-1}x'y
$$

and

$$
\hat\phi\sim N(\phi,(x'x)^{-1}var(e))
$$

But $\phi=\beta^2$ that is $\hat\beta= \pm \sqrt{\hat\phi}$. Putting it in the equation above leads to,
$$
\hat\beta\sim N(\pm\beta,(x'x)^{-1}var(e))
$$
The last equation shows that the sampling distribution of the estimated parameter is not consistant in sign. Then the estimation is not BLUE!

Comment: brilliant! I've been struggling with that for years! I gave you kudos here in case you're interested (and in case you're interested in seeing all the other nonsensical answers.....) https://www.reddit.com/r/CFA/comments/m2r41g/linear_regression_question/